# Slow queries on Amazon Aurora with index (Wordpress Database)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora database instance with some performance issues. One is particularly strange. I have a WordPress installation with the standard wp_options table. In this table I have added an index on the autoload column. Schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_options` (
`option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`option_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`option_value` longtext NOT NULL,
`autoload` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1045503 ;
ALTER TABLE `wp_options` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`), ADD KEY `index_autoload` (`autoload`);
```

The strange thing is I see a lot of queries like this in the slow log:
    SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'

It can even take a whole minute to run. I have many of this every day. 
The only hint I have is the (relatively) big amount of rows which is 6602 rows. 5913 rows have autoload = 'yes'

Table size is 26.2 MB

Comment: 5319 autoloading WordPress options?  Holy cow, that is an enormous number!  You may want to look through your plugins and see which one is doing this.

Comment: Sure it is, yet I believe a server with 30GB of memory, doing only that, on SSD as Amazon Aurora is should perform better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you flushed the garbage out of your dbms.

The index you created won't help because it has a very low cardinality. That column has only two possible values in a typical WordPress installation. So, the query planner will probably still do a full table scan and ignore the index.

A slightly better index for that particular query might be `(autoload, option_name, option_value)`. That's a [covering index](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727). The query can be satisfied entirely from the index, which saves a bit of time on the server. But probably not in your case.

Part of the performance hit on WordPress queries comes from the inevitable time-cost of transferring the data from the DBMS machine to the WordPress host. No amount of big iron on either the DBMS or the WordPress side is going to do much for that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved deleting lots and lots of rows